# Delete a file on Firebase storage when offline

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm developing an android app and I've been researching on the web a way to delete a file on firebase storage when I'm **offline**, but unfortunately, I haven't found anything! The closest result I found was how to resume a file uploading.

I'd like to know if there's a way to do it like the Firebase Realtime database which allows the data persistence, I mean, when the connection turns on, the file is deleted automatically.

Thank you in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storage isn't persistence. Just database. You can't do an action on storage when you're offline and expect to be performed when you become online.

Comment: H'm... I though about it...
So, do you mean that I need the user becaming online to perform the actions?

Comment: Yes, user need to have an internet connection.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for your fast answer!

Comment: Year, for sure! I'm just waiting the minimum time to accept it! Would you mind to up vote the question? And I will be able to up vote your answer too.

Answer (score 3):

Actually with Cloud Functions it is fairly easy to implement what you want.

1. Read this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions
2. Create an onDisconnect event (client side) -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect
3. Create a [onWrite event (server side, cloud function)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) that will be triggered when the onDisconnect event occurs.
4. In that onWrite event you can do whatever you want in your storage :)

Comment: I'd actually use an [`onDelete` trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#set_the_event_handler). But aside from that: sounds like a very valid approach.

Comment: Thank you J. Doe for this approach! I'll try this!